# Mapping keys at Vim's "Press Enter" prompt

Tags: vim

After a command such as `:ls`, Vim displays a list, followed by the prompt:

> Press Enter or type command to continue

For example:

```
:ls
  2  a    ".vimrc"                 line 24
  3 #a    "dotfiles/README.md"     line 13
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Typing `:` here allows me to compose an Ex-mode command while the list is present.  This works fine.  (See `:help hit-enter`.)

However, I have mapped <kbd>Space</kbd> to `:` in normal mode (because it's much easier to press <kbd>Space</kbd> than <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>).  Unfortunately, my muscle memory causes me to press <kbd>Space</kbd> at the "Press ENTER" prompt when I mean `:`.  <kbd>Space</kbd> is mapped to <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which closes the list and the prompt.  I would rather it map to `:`.

Is it possible to map keys in the "Press ENTER" prompt?

Comment: Is this a nitpicky problem?  Yes.  I would still like a solution though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this semi-famous mapping as a workaround:

```
nnoremap <key> :ls<CR>:b
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing something like that.  Might be the best option.